# Tumblr theme getting tags of a post in JavaScript

Tags: html, escaping, tumblr

I want to use the tags of a post in JavaScript. To get the tags I was originally using something like the following:

```
<article class="post" data-tags="{TagsAsClasses}">
```

This worked fine up until I needed to use special characters like `|` which becomes a `_` with this property and gives me the wrong tag.

So now I need to do something like (using the `{block:Tags}`):

```
<article class="post" data-tags="{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}{Tag}{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}">
```

Yet I foresee problems if `{Tag}` ever has a double quote in it.

Is there any way I can keep the data-tags attribute and still use `{block:Tags}` to get the real tag?

I have come up with a solution that involves adding and then reading a bunch of markup but I just don't like it as much.

```
<div class="postHiddenTags" style="display:none;">
    {block:HasTags}
        {block:Tags}<div data-tag={JSTag} data-tagURL={JSTagURL}></div>{/block:Tags}
    {/block:HasTags}
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need the tag URL, as your current workaround suggests?

Comment: Nope, I do not need it

Comment: Why not use `data-tags` except with `{JSTag}` instead of `{Tag}`? Why add the extra div?

Comment: Won't that make a bunch of quoted strings? So for each tag I'd get data-tags="tag1" "tag2" "tag3", there's no way to specify the JS prefix without using the quotes that come with it, so I can't wrap them in my own quotes.

Comment: I made a room where you can't talk, here's a new one: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88748/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the tags in JavaScript, you can define them in a `<script>` tag from the start. In your theme HTML:

```
<script>
    var tags = {};

    {block:Posts}
    {block:HasTags}
    tags[{JSPostID}] = [
        {block:Tags}
        {
            "tag": {JSTag},
            "tagURL": {JSTagURL},
        },
        {/block:Tags}
    ];
    {/block:HasTags}
    {/block:Posts}
</script>
```

You have a global JavaScript dictionary, from a post's ID to its list of tags (and tag URLs). The "JS" prefix is to output the string [wrapped in quotes](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#variable-transformations).

In each of your post elements, add an attribute for the post ID:

```
{block:Posts}
<article data-id="{PostID}" class="post"></article>
{/block:Posts}
```

You can have `{block:Posts}` multiple times in your template, although [the theme documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts) does not mention this.

Whenever you need a post's tags, get the post ID from its DOM element, then look up the ID in the tag dictionary. This way you don't have to worry about escaping/un-escaping special characters.